# Why are my model params being considered an undefined local variable?:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fields-for, undefined-variable

I have an app with three models. The primary model has_one of the other two models, and and the secondary models belongs_to the primary model.

The first model has two views, each with a form that populates the primary model and part of its respective secondary model. The first view is called new, and I simply created another view entitled new2, as they both populate the primary model's database.

In both my forms, I have:

```
  <%= f.fields_for @primarymodel.secondary_model do |secondary_model_field| %>
```

I don't have a controller for the secondary models, and in my primary model controller I have defined the params to include all attributes from all thee models.

When I attempt to submit the forms in dev mode, I get an error that my params are an "undefined local variable."

The params *are* defined in the controller.

The create in the controller is:

```
 def create
     @primarymodel= Primarymodel.create(primarymodel_params)
    @primarymodel.save

end
```

Is there a reason that params would show up as an undefined variable?

Update: 
Here is my whole controller

```
    class ParticipantsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @participant= Participant.new
  end

  def new2
    # @participant= Participant.new
  end

  def create
     @participant = Participant.create(participant_params)
    @participant.save
    if @participant.save
            flash[:success] = "Successfully Registered!"        

            #email notifes admin of new registration
        NotifyMailer.notify_email(@participant).deliver_now

        redirect_to '/signup'
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  def show
  end

  def index
  end

 private
    def participant_params
      params.require(:participant).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :gender, :email, :birthdate, :phone, :street_name, :city, :state, :zip, :baptism_date, :baptism_importance, :christian_story, :questions, :nationality, :religion, :need_ride, 
        :has_spouse, :spouse_name, :english_level, :expectations, :length_of_stay, :exact_length, :volunteer_id, :matched, :returned_home)

    end

  end
end
```

Here is the server error:

```
Started POST "/participants" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-14 21:15:38 -0600
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by ParticipantsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"oMlCbilHzH18I9WmwqweShDLa3vhPy8d+t4cdsU8fSR2ReijiwMhIOmdi0vzQfdsO4rwD3OqGRR7ZvLshOuFtg==", "participant"=>{"first_name"=>"J", "last_name"=>"W", "gender"=>"Male", "email"=>"j@xxxx.com", "phone"=>"xxxxxxxxxx", "street_name"=>"41 Belling", "city"=>"Nashville", "state"=>"Tennessee", "zip"=>"", "role"=>"Reader", "student_details"=>{"nationality"=>"", "religion"=>"", "birthdate"=>"", "need_ride"=>"Yes", "has_spouse"=>"married", "spouse_name"=>"", "english_level"=>"Low", "expectations"=>"", "length_of_stay"=>"Less than 1 Year", "exact_length"=>""}}, "commit"=>"Register"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 445ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
NameError (undefined local variable or method `participant_params' for #<ParticipantsController:0x0000000008915228>
Did you mean?  participant_path
               participant_url
               participants_path):
 
app/controllers/participants_controller.rb:11:in `create'
  Rendering C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (8.0ms)
  Rendering C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.8ms)
  Rendering C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (2.9ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (1881.1ms)
```

This is the model:

```
class Participant < ApplicationRecord
                                validates :last_name, presence: true
                                # validates :gender, inclusion: { in: %w(male female) }
                                validates :nationality, presence: true
                                validates :phone, presence: true
                                has_one :volunteer_detail
                                has_one :reader_detail
end
```

Comment: Can we have some codes, for better understanding instead of primary secondary ...?

Comment: Added my controller

Comment: Can you add model also?

Comment: And add a server log for failed action with error stacktrace, please

Comment: Added server log and model

Comment: Are you sure that's your whole controller? If so, you have a missing `end` for your `create` method. You only `end` the `if` statement, not the actual method.

Comment: Sorry, I must have not copied the entire controller. It is there now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your `create` method:

```
def create
    @participant = Participant.create(participant_params)
    @participant.save
    if @participant.save
      flash[:success] = "Successfully Registered!"        

      #email notifes admin of new registration
      NotifyMailer.notify_email(@participant).deliver_now

      redirect_to '/signup'
  end
```

As you can see, you don't `end` the method, you only have an `end` for the `if` statement. This means that when you define other methods like `edit` and `participant_params` they are defined within the `create` method.

Change your `create` method so that you `end` both the `if` statement and the method like so:

```
def create
    @participant = Participant.create(participant_params)
    @participant.save
    if @participant.save
      flash[:success] = "Successfully Registered!"        

      #email notifes admin of new registration
      NotifyMailer.notify_email(@participant).deliver_now

      redirect_to '/signup'
    end
 end
```

(Notice the last `end`, you currently have that at the bottom of your file rather than here)

Comment: Thanks Carl, I was staring at that for hours and couldn’t find where it was going wrong!

Comment: No problems :) Quick tip though, use `deliver_later` not `deliver_now`. This way the email will be sent in the background, freeing up the rest of your code execution

Comment: thanks for the tip- does deliver_later have an option for a delay?